# How to represent a vector in terms of another vector?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, matrix-equations

If $u, v$ be two unit vectors. $\textbf{Then how to represent $u$ in terms of $v$? }$

I can find a matrix, $R$ such that $u=Rv$, from trial and error. How to derive the matrix analytically?

Unit vectors essentially represent direction. So $\cos(x)= u.v $  should be giving the angle between $u$ and $v$.

P.S: I am looking for the relationship between the eigenvectors of two different matrices. 
I know that a scalar multiplication of one vector will not give another vector.

Comment: Could you post everything you know about the two vectors? If the vectors are in 2D, then you could describe the vector $v$ as the value along $u$ and the value along the perpendicular of $u$. However, this does not work in higher dimensions. Eg: consider the vectors $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 2)$. There is no way to express $(0, 1, 2)$ in terms of just $(1, 0, 0)

Comment: @SiddharthBhat vectors are of any dimensions. I was thinking maybe it could be rotated as a unit vector represents direction.

Comment: If $u\cdot v\neq 1$ then $u,v$ are not parallel, so any scalar multiplie of $u$, say, i.e. $\lambda u$, can't possibly be equal to $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u,v$ are unit vectors, the matrix $R=uv^T$ does the trick:
$$
Rv = uv^Tv = u.
$$